# Do I have to free memory allocated by New in a Opencv C wrapper for the C++ interface

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm writing C wrappers for C++ OpenCV functions,  here is one I did

```
Mat* cv_create_ones(int rows, int cols, int type) {
    return new Mat(Mat::ones(rows, cols, type));
}
```

In most of the wrappers I return as above by calling New first. I was wondering do I have to free the data allocated by New in my wrapper with delete when I'm done with it... If so is there a way to incorporate delete into the above wrapper so It is called automatically when the function is done  being used...Like maybe every time its called it creates a New,  gets used then calls delete...only to call new again when its accessed again....No that wouldn't work because If I store data in the pointer allocated by new it would get deleted, right? I googled for how to do this and I didn't find anything. Any advice from a pro on this is appreciated.

Edit for Dima Maligin

I tried the below and juanchopanza's in addition to variations on his but get errors

```
Mat* cv_create_zeros(int rows, int cols, int type) {
    Mat m(Mat::ones(rows, cols, type)); return &m;;
}
```

on this one in particular I get

warning: address of local variable ‘m’ returned

I googled and it seems in this case using malloc is recomended but then It would need to be freed...So if you know a workaround I would be grateful.  I'm adding new functions to Arjun Comars Opencv pull on github,  its getting ready to merged with the main and its addition is to autogenerate C wrappers for C++ code so languages without a c++ ffi can wrap opencv c++ function. An example of this is here on github https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv/blob/master/modules/c/src/mat.cpp...I was hoping someone can look at the link, which is some of the wrappers and most do use "new" and won't compile without it, and tell me if using  them I'm supposed to arrange for the memory to be freed later...If you can maybe divine his intention of the code and give me advice I would appreciate it...

Comment: You do, but you are missing the point of the C++ interface of OpenCV. Let `cv::Mat` manage its own resources. Don't dynamically allocate it.

Comment: @juanchopanza  Can you be more detailed....Do you mean I don't have to call New ...I got this code from a person working for opencv so I think it's right.....could I be mistaken..Is it wrong ...pls elaborate

Comment: yes, no need `new`, see opencv docs also http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#automatic-memory-management

Comment: Just say something like `cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::ones(rows, cols, type);`. I really see no advantage in using `new` here.

Comment: @juanchopanza I just did a quick test and without the new the above function won't compile, I get  opencv-glue.cpp:190:43: error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘cv::Mat*’ in return
     return Mat(Mat::ones(rows, cols, type));
                                           ^

Comment: You don't need the function. Just use the line I posted in my previous comment. To make the function compile, it needs to return `Mat`, not `Mat*`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I just did tested and without the new above function won't compile, I get  

'opencv-glue.cpp:190:43: error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘cv::Mat*’in return
     return Mat(Mat::ones(rows, cols, type));'

The above function is from the C wrappers that are auto_generated on a version of OpenCV that is poised to merge with the main...So if opencv is saying this is good code...Then its good right?  Or are you guys so good you can see the holes in professional code, who should I believe=) I could use help getting to compile without the new
                                           ^

Comment: A pointer to an object is not the same as an object of that type. You need to read a basic C++ book.

Comment: Oh I see, you are writing C wrappers for the  C++ wrappers? Why nor use the C API directly?

Comment: `Mat m(Mat::ones(rows, cols, type));`  
`return &m;`
should work.

Comment: @Dima Maligin Thanks for your reply....Pls see latest edits

Comment: @juanchopanza...The C api isn't good c++ has way more functions...Pls see latest edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You can't create a local variable and return a reference or pointer to it

therefore:

```
Mat* cv_create_zeros(int rows, int cols, int type) {
    Mat m(Mat::ones(rows, cols, type)); return &m;;
}
```

is illegal. you return a pointer to deleted object.

2- Any `new` you did, you must `delete`.

therefore if called:

```
Mat* cv_create_ones(int rows, int cols, int type) {
    return new Mat(Mat::ones(rows, cols, type));
}
```

the pointer must be deleted using `delete`.
since you writing a c wrapper and you can't use `delete` you should add a `delete_mat` function.

```
void delete_mat(Mat* m)
{
   delete m;
}
```

**EDIT**

Since the `delete` is not mean only to free the memory, it also mean to call the destructor, You need delete function for each type you need to delete, or, to be more precise, at least for each base type with a virtual destructur.

You **don't** need to add a delete function for each function uses `new`, you need only for each **type**.

Like if you have 2 (or more) functions:

```
Mat* cv_create_ones(...){
  return new Mat(Mat::ones(...));
}
Mat* cv_create_zeroes(...){
  return new Mat(Mat::zeroes(...));
}
```

You need only one `delete` function to delete a Mat pointer:

```
void delete_mat(Mat* m)
{
  delete m;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply...I'm have a ton of functions that use new that are c wrappers for opencv c++ here is my file http://pastebucket.com/32401 ...does that mean I have to write a delete  function for each object in each function that instantiates an object with delete...I'm trying to keep my code from getting chunky...is this the only way....

Comment: @EdwardMonney I thought it was obvious, see the edit in the answer.